# How to validate/test (like F1 score does) the results of my shortest path algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, shortest-path

I was thinking of using the F1 score in finding out if my A* search algorithm did great or not. The thing is, the outputs of the algorithm are route, distance, and estimated time from the origin to its destination. I don't have any idea where to get the False Negative or True Negative numbers with these outputs. Is there any other way to test the results and interpret them using formulas like F1?

Comment: If your heuristic always underestimates the real costs A* is guaranteed to find the(if there are more than on best, one of them)  BEST solution. So a *F1 score* does not make sense because A* finds in 100% of all cases the best solution.

Comment: So how should I present my results? Just tabulate them? And I need to discuss the results further.

Comment: You could compare the computation-time (or number of explored steps until the solution was found) in comparison to other search strategies (or different heuristics used for A*).

Comment: Thank you. I have another question. Is it okay if I compare the results of my A* search algorithm with the results that Google Directions API provide?

Comment: If you used A* correctly no other algorithm could find a better solution. I don't know the Google Directions API but you can compare if it finds worse solutions of needs more time to find them.